# Resizing d3 / dagre-d3 svg to show all contents

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, dagre-d3

I'm trying to create DAGs with [dagre-d3](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3). The data for these DAGs comes from a database, are different for each DAG and as such, I do not know the width/height to give the containing svg before adding all nodes and edges to the graph.

So ideally I'd call something like `d3.select("#svg1").resize_to_match_contents()` after adding all nodes and edges to make sure all nodes are visible and the svg isn't too large. Of course there is no such function, and I have no idea how to implement it. I know I can call `d3.select("#svg1").attr("height", "10")` to set the height, but have no idea how to retreive/compute what the height of the `<g>` element inside the SVG is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The internal and external dimensions of SVG can be independently controlled using the [*viewBox*](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html) attribute. When you talk about finding the *size of the `g`* element, it only makes sense if there there is no `viewBox` defined and there are no other *scale* transformations anywhere.

[image: svg width height and viewBox]

Here is how I would suggest you do it:

1. Set the `width`/`height` of the `svg` element to the `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`, or to the maximum dimension you want it to grow to.
2. Set the `viewBox` attribute to something like `"0 0 100 100"` and then define all scales in your code to have the domain `[0, 100]`. This will ensure that the graph *shrinks* to fit in your designated area.

Also, take a look at how [`nvd3` handles window resizes](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/utils.js#L32), and how to maintain the coordinate system inside the SVG element upon resize using [preserveAspectRatio](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute).

---

From what I could glean from their webpage, darge-d3 does not allow for setting the layout options to limit the render size explicitly and does not return the maximum dimensions it used. One could, however, use [`getBBox()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) to get the dimensions of the `g` box where it rendered and try to set the `viewBox` such that it *just* fits the SVG (or set the `height`, `width` on the SVG to match the dimension for the `g` 1:1, but that could lead to a broken layout.

Comment: Thanks, `getBBox()` was the key. This works: `var bbox = d3.select("#svg{{ loop.index }}").node().getBBox();
 d3.select("#svg{{ loop.index }}").attr("height", bbox.height + 40).attr('width', bbox.width + 40);`

Comment: Just a heads up - dagre-d3 now exposes width and height attributes on the layout graph. For an example, take a look at: https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3/blob/master/demo/sentence-tokenization.html#L85.

Comment: In a nutshell, is the answer just "use the viewbox property of svg to resize the dagre output to fit"? nowadays dagre exposes the output dimensions so getbbox is probably not necessary anymore.

Comment: Does anyone know of a Fiddle/Plunk showing auto-zoom?